# Davening Weekday davening on Shabbos

Tags: halacha, tefilla, shabbat

If someone mistakenly began davening the weekday Shmone Esrei (amidah) on Shabbos, and he caught himself in the middle of a bracha, he must complete that bracha before he goes on to daven the shabbos davening.
The reason for this is since really one should have been obligated to say the full (weekday) davening even on Shabbos, but the chachamim did not want to burden us, so they made a shorter davening for Shabbos, thus the any bracha of the weekday davening is also for Shabbos and therefore he must complete that bracha and only then change to Shabbos davening.(Brachos 21a,Shulchan aruch OHC 268 and Mishne Brurah 268:2).

Question: If  someone accidentally said the entire weekday shmone esrei on Shabbos and then remembered that it was Shabbos, and since he didn't mention Shabbos he must now daven the shmone esrei of shabbos. If in his second time he then also accidentally began the weekday brachos does he need to finish the bracha he's in? We might say that since the only reason one finishes the bracha is because really one should have been obligated to say the full (weekday) davening even on shabbos, but this person has already said the whole weekday davening, and he now needs only the Shabbos brachos, so why should he complete the weekday bracha?

Comment: I don't see why this is different from forgetting Yaaleh veYavo where you have to repeat everything, not just say some Yuntif-esque bracha and be done. It's not like since you already said the weekday Berakhot you aren't obligated to say then again once you forget the Mein HaMeora

Comment: Maybe he should just give up the attempt.

Comment: @DoubleAA from the fact that one who davened the whole weekday shmone esrei on Shabbos only needs to daven the Shabbos shmone esrei without repeating any of the weekday brachos we see that this is different than yaaleh veyavo. One must only finish the (weekday) bracha he is in the middle of, - because of his chiyuv to daven the weekday shmone esrei but if he already did so before why would he need to finish the weekday part of the bracha.

Comment: "from the fact that one who davened the whole weekday shmone esrei on Shabbos only needs to daven the Shabbos shmone esrei without repeating any of the weekday brachos we see that this is different than yaaleh veyavo." How do we see that? That's not different at all from the Yaaleh veYavo case. It's the exact same thing. In both cases you redo as if from the beginning ignoring the first try. I don't know what difference you see, like I asked above. You just asserted again that there is a difference without telling me what it is.

Comment: I don’t see how this is different than yaale veyavo either. When the person is chayav to daven a second amida because he forgot Shabbos - in his repeat, he should really recite the entire thing with both shabbos and weekday, and the chachamim went easy on him and said only do shabbos - but if he went into weekday mode the same svara to finish it should apply. His failed attempt I don’t think accomplished anything in terms of fulfilling his amida recitation requirement.

Comment: @Draizy-LeviPine so if you think that's the answer why don't you put it as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the person is chayav to daven a second amida because he forgot Shabbos - in his repeat, he should really recite the entire thing with both shabbos and weekday, and the chachamim went easy on him and said only do shabbos - but if he went into weekday mode the same svara to finish it should apply. His failed attempt I don’t think accomplished anything in terms of fulfilling his amida recitation requirement

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  I think it is complete and correct. (I deleted the irrelevant introduction).

Comment: What is the source, that " he should really recite the entire thing with both shabbos and weekday" if already davened. During the weekday we don't say that (oh"c 107/1), so why on Shabbos should he have to say the weekday amida a second time?

Comment: @user17260 I’m not sure if I follow your comment. That Halacha is by a nedava - but here where he didn’t fulfil his obligation whatsoever because he neglected shabbos in his recitation, he in no way fulfilled his obligation to daven - why should he not have to re do it over?

Comment: Draizy-Levi-Pine - There are two separate tefilos one should  theoretically say on Shabbos [by each amida], one about kedushas Shabbos, and one where he requests his needs. Chaza"l do not want us to ask for our needs on shabbos, but if one starts by mistake, he may complete that bracha. That part of the tefila has nothing to do with the kedushas Shabbos part. If one already requested his needs [by mistake], that part of the tefilla is never repeated. Maybe you can help me understand why failing to say the kedusas Sabbos part, makes it necessary to ask for his needs again?